# Bootstrap 3 Reorder columns for mobile and tablet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I using Bootstrap 3 and im trying to reorder the columns position in mobile and tablet.

How is this possible?

this is my code:

```
<div class="row main-row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia illum recusandae delectus assumenda adipisci minima eaque! Tempore sit eius error, enim, voluptatem repudiandae dolorem atque fugiat aperiam placeat, corporis consequuntur.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

*I want to Bootstrap to show* 

Text 
Image 
Text 
Image

*Right now it shows*

Image
Text
Text
Image

Is there a way to handle this?

[What it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNF1h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use flex in the mobile version.

```css
 .main-row {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
        }

            .main-row .col-md-6 {
                display: flex;
                order: 1;
            }

            .main-row .col-md-6 +.col-md-6 {
                display: flex;
                order: 0;
            }
```

```html
<div class="row main-row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia illum recusandae delectus assumenda adipisci minima eaque! Tempore sit eius error, enim, voluptatem repudiandae dolorem atque fugiat aperiam placeat, corporis consequuntur.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    IMGES
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Bootstrap 3 you cannot change the order of columns in smaller screens but you can do that in large screens. In Bootstrap 4 you can now change the order of columns in smaller screens. Below you can see one way of doing this.

```
<div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        main
    </div>
</div>
```